# I need to rename the key of the json object that I generate in java

Tags: java, json, lambda, java-stream

I do a list merge and I create a new one, but when I do that the key of json is the id and I wanted it to be a fixed name.

I create the list this way.
I don't know if it's the most efficient way but it's the only one I got.

```
public Map<Object, NotasMateriaDTO> buscaNotavfffsTipoList(Integer idusuario) {

    List<NotasMateria> notasMaterias = repository.findAll(Sort.by("dataNota").descending());
    List<Materia> materias = materiaRepository.findAll();
    ModelMapper mapper = new ModelMapper();

    List<NotasMateriaDTO> filter1 =
            notasMaterias.stream()
                    .filter(t -> t.getIdUsuario()== idusuario)
                    .map(mt -> mapper.map(mt, NotasMateriaDTO.class))
                    .collect(Collectors.toList());

    List<NotasMateriaDTO> filter2  = materias.stream()
            .filter(t ->t.getIdUsuario() ==(idusuario))
            .map(mt -> mapper.map(mt, NotasMateriaDTO.class))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    Map<Object, NotasMateriaDTO> serverMap1 = filter1.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(NotasMateriaDTO::getIdMateria, Function.identity()));
    Map<Object, NotasMateriaDTO> serverMap2 = filter2.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(NotasMateriaDTO::getIdMateria, Function.identity()));
    serverMap1.keySet().forEach(key -> serverMap1.merge(key,
            serverMap2.get(key),
            (server1, server2) -> {
                server1.setNomeMateria(server2.getNomeMateria());
                return server1;
            }));
    return  serverMap1;
}
```

this way it returns that list:

```
{
    "18": {
        "idNotaMateria": 1,
        "idMateria": 18,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 4.0,
        "nomeMateria": "dfsdf"
    },
    "10": {
        "idNotaMateria": 3,
        "idMateria": 10,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 10.0,
        "nomeMateria": "materia123"
    },
    "14": {
        "idNotaMateria": 6,
        "idMateria": 14,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 432.0,
        "nomeMateria": "mat123"
    }
}
```

wish she looks like this:

```
{
    "anyName": {
        "idNotaMateria": 1,
        "idMateria": 18,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 4.0,
        "nomeMateria": "dfsdf"
    },
    "anyName": {
        "idNotaMateria": 3,
        "idMateria": 10,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 10.0,
        "nomeMateria": "materia123"
    },
    "anyName": {
        "idNotaMateria": 6,
        "idMateria": 14,
        "idUsuario": 7,
        "notaMateria": 432.0,
        "nomeMateria": "mat123"
    }
}
```

Comment: simple question, what will you do with all object with same key ?

Comment: to be easier to manipulate on the front end

Comment: post NotasMateriaDTO and I will help you out

Comment: '@Getter
@Setter
public class NotasMateriaDTO {

    private int idNotaMateria;
    private int idMateria;
    private int idUsuario;
    private Double notaMateria;
    private String nomeMateria;
}
'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So checking your question. To achieve what you want has no meaning considering you should not have a json object that contains multiple objects with the same names

The following makes no sense

```
  { 
       name: { object 1},
       name: { object 2}
    }
```

The following is what makes sense in your situation

```
    [ 
       { object 1 },
       { object 2}
    ]
```

Just configure your method to return an array of those objects. That will make sense

```
public List<NotasMateriaDTO> buscaNotavfffsTipoList(Integer idusuario)
```